# Capybara::ElementNotFound: for jquery ui dialog box content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I have my Login form into the Jquery UI Dialog popup box. When I start doing RSpec test, I got an error with

```
Failure/Error: fill_in "Username", with: "user@example.com"
Capybara::ElementNotFound
cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Username' found
```

Here is my spec/request page:

```
describe "create user", :js => true do

  before { visit new_enr_rds_dea_path }

  let(:submit) { "Create Dea" }

  describe "with invalid information" do
    it "should not create a user" do
      expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(Enr::Rds::Dea, :count)
    end
  end

  describe "with valid information" do
    before do
      fill_in "Username", with: "user@example.com"
      fill_in "Password", with: "foobar"
      fill_in "Confirm password", with: "foobar"
      fill_in "Organisation", with: "foobar"
    end

    it "should create a user" do
      expect { click_link_or_button submit }.to change(Enr::Rds::Dea, :count).by()
    end
  end
```

Factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :dea_user do |user|
    user.dea_user             "example@in4systems.com"
    user.dea_pwd              "foobar"
    user.dea_pwd_confirmation "foobar"
    user.pro_organisation_id  "NHER"
  end
end
```

I am rendering my new and edit page to the Form partial. Both `New` and `edit` button has `:remote => true` method to open the JqueryUI dialog box. Thanks..

Comment: Which capybara driver are you using? Make sure it support javascript.

Comment: The newest version of Capybara apparently has been modified to throw an error if the exact element is not found.  This could be part of the problem...

Comment: I know it sounds like a generic answer but I'd recommend using `launchy` (it's a very handy gem) and using `save_and_open_page` right before `fill_in "Username", with: "user@example.com"`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 describe "with valid information" do
    before do
      fill_in "username text-input-field-id", :with => "user@example.com"
      ...
      ...
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

replace with the id of the field, as Dipak suggests or use all lowercase.  Sometimes it's not `Username` but just `username` that Capybara is seeing... or Seleminum to be exact.